# Can I combine values from C# variable and XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a requirement where the email body should contain textbox inputted value. I have predefined contents in email body of xml format but inputted value from the textbox should append to the xml & with this inputted value whole email body should display in the placeholder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EMAIL> 
  <ADDR To="abcd@abcd.com" Sub="Email body"></ADDR>  
  <BODY>Data available at &lt;br /&gt;**url&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Thanks</BODY>
</EMAIL>
```

In C#,

```
 public void EmailDefaultValue(string url)
    {
        XElement xmlMap = XElement.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Config Files/EmailBody.xml"));
        txtToEmail.Value = (from item in xmlMap.Elements("ADDR")
                            select item.Attribute("To").Value).Single();
        txtSubject.Value = (from item in xmlMap.Elements("ADDR")
                            select item.Attribute("Sub").Value).Single();
        txtEmailBody.Text =string.Format((from item in xmlMap.Elements("BODY")
                             select item.Value).Single(),url);
    }
```

in output:
a text `**url` displayed instead of reading the `url` variable value and appending.
where am i missing and what?

Comment: You'll have to serialise your answer back to the XML file using a XMLWriter.

Comment: actually i dont need to save this inputted value in my predefined xml. since it may gets changed at any point of time. i tried adding a new xml node & insert after particular node. and able to read that value as well. but it doesnt satisfy my requirement. anyways i have got the answer with help of  har07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your string that need to be substituted by [`String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting) has to be in a certain format, for example, `{0}`. Replace `**url` in your XML template to `{0}` :

```
<BODY>Data available at &lt;br /&gt;{0}&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Thanks</BODY>
```

Then your current code should work. Quick test : https://dotnetfiddle.net/U5LHep

Comment: thank u so much sir. it worked exactly as i expected. i appreciate ur quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below one.

```
[XmlRoot]
public class EMAIL
{
    [XmlElement("ADDR")]
    public ADDR ADDR { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("BODY")]
    public string BODY { get; set; }
}

public class ADDR
{
    [XmlAttribute("To")]
    public string To { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Sub")]
    public string Sub { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{            
        var fileName = @"your xml file here";
        var xmlResult = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EMAIL));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlResult))
        {
            EMAIL result = (EMAIL)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            Console.WriteLine(result.ADDR.Sub);
            Console.WriteLine(result.ADDR.To);
            Console.WriteLine(result.BODY);
        }

        Console.Read();
}
```

And your output

[image]